# How to prevent concurrency attack on Laravel without using queues

Tags: php, laravel, concurrency

How to prevent concurrency attack on Laravel without using queues?

suppose i have a product and its quantity is 1,
two requests send to buy this product at the same time,
**i can use queue without overlap to solve it** but queue have some issue, i can't return **direct response to the customer if it "sold out" or not** for the field  request to buy this product due another one bought it. so only one request should success and another one should failed due sold out

my real case , the product is booking system rooms in hotel, and the result will be sold out or not is based on search period, so  calculation of number of available rooms not stored in database, i should calculate it

**is there any way to solve it without queue like synchronize method in java?**

Comment: This is one of the reasons you use a decent DBMS! The ability to record lock so this does not happen. Think TRANSACTIONS

Comment: I suppose the obvious question now would be "What DBMS are you using"? Just to be sure you are not using something that cannot cope

Comment: im using MySQL Database, im using transaction , but it will not solve it

Comment: So what is the actual problem you are seeing?

Comment: my real case , the product is booking system like hotel, and the result will be sold out or not is based on search period, so  calculation of number of available spots not stored in database, should calculate it

Comment: ok, so if I am updating the table/row my script should lock the row/table. Your search will wait until I unlock with a commit